# oracle stored procedure returning a sys_refcursor. I need to execute the sp using c# .net and return it as Json

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g

oracle stored procedure returning a sys_refcursor. I need to execute the sp using c# .net and return it as Json I am passing all the input parameter values, specifying output parameter direction and executing command.ExecuteReader() statement. Now how to capture the out parameter sys_refcursor ?

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thank you for showing interest in answering my question. Actually I figured out a way to do it. I loaded the datareader to a data table object and using data table visualizer, I found all the column names of the ref_cursor and it's data. So, I wrote a for loop to read each datarow & added to a list. Finally returned the list.